# Call PHP variable in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

The Call of this PHP Code below in Smarty will not work

Sample Usage in PHP

```
$content=@file_get_contents("http://www.gempixel.com/short/api/?url=http://www.google.com&api=APIKEY");

$url=json_decode($content,TRUE);//Decodes json into an array

if(!$url["error"]){  // If there is no error
echo $url["short"]; //Outputs the short url
}else{ 
echo $url["msg"]; //Outputs the error message
}
```

For Smarty I just need to replace php with {php} and it should work.

```
{php}$shortenedurl = file_get_contents('http://www.gempixel.com/short/api/?api=fAaFjILdbigF&url=' . urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));{/php}

{php}$url=json_decode($content,TRUE);if(!$url["error"]){echo $url["short"];}else{echo $url["msg"];}{/php}
```

But it will not call the string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of templates was to separate the code from the design...

Comment: @OneTrickPony, Mate thanks you open my eyes ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to assign varible value to smarty

```
$iframe="hiii";
$smarty->assign( 'iframe', $iframe ); //$smarty is a global var to assign
```

then get it your .tpl file

```
{$iframe}
```